# highlight and copy The entire text of iframe in html

Tags: html, iframe, copy, highlight

How can we highlight  and copy the entire text of iframe in html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you can't do it.
Simply, use browsers like Chrome or Firefox, right click on the part you want to copy in the iframe, and choose View Frame Source. You should be getting the code inside the iframe.